# Android Map overlay gives null pointer exception

Tags: android, google-maps, mapactivity

I'm storing my latitude and longitude in content provider as a real type.

When I retrieve it using a cursor, I use `.getDouble`, which means now this is a double.

This method accepts lat and long in only int type `newGeoPoint ( latitude, longitude )`

When I tried converting lat and lon from double to int, I get java null pointer exception.

This is what I tried Int(latitude * 1E6); Can you shed some light on this?

**Update**

I converted this double value to string then passed it to toast, I'm getting the values in toast. Now the problem is, how do I convert from double to int with out losing the float part.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There's not enough info for us to help you here. Post logcat messages, code, and anything that might be relevant. a NPE can come from a variety of things

Comment: @dymmeh:Log cat showing error on newGeoPoint(latitude ,longitude); null pointer exception.

Comment: @dymmeh:tell me,generally how people do this using content provider.

Comment: If you are using the data type Double (not double.. notice the "D" capital) your latitude and longitude values "might" be null. It's really impossible to say without seeing your code.

Comment: @dymmeh:Pls,read my question properly,i've not mentioned any where saying ,i'm using Long.

Comment: I edited my comment to say "Double".. The same principle applies..

Comment: @dymmeh:It is D,see my update.

Comment: Does your call look like this? newGeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1e6), (int)(longitude * 1e6));

Comment: @dymmeh:Nope, it is like this ,Integer l =(integer) (lo * 1E6);

Comment: Try like how i posted and report back. You are trying to create an Integer object without actually initializing the integer..

Comment: @dymmeh:Worked like a charm,what is diff b/w ur syntax and mine.

Comment: I'm not even sure how you got Integer l =(integer) (lo * 1E6); to work. That shouldn't even compile

Answer (score 0):

Try casting after multiplying:

```
int longitude = (int) (longitudeInDouble * 1E6)
```